# How to set log4j with unlimited max file size?

Tags: java, log4j

I didn't get a definitive answer to this question by Google'ing, so I pose it to the groupthink masterminds and to ensure that a quality answer **can** be Google-able in the future.

Using log4j RollingFileAppender, I can set the maximum size I want the file to reach before rolling over on itself, like so:

```
RollingFileAppender rfa = new RollingFileAppender();
rfa.setMaximumFileSize(500000000); // Sets the max file size to 500MB
```

Now, what if I **don't ever** want this file to be rolled over? How do I set the RollingFileAppender maximum file size to unlimited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when they reach a certain size.

If you don't want to roll it over, then simply use [`FileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE). Then you're already on a *technical* limit.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `FileAppender`.

Answer (score 2):

talking peanuts:

make sure your filesystem does support the filesize you want to achive. technically it will never be an unlimited filesize due to filesystem restrictions.