# Log large xml files with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to log a large xml file (about 1mb) with log4j but I keep getting this error:

log4j:ERROR Detected overflow, aborting until it is resolved.  Last log request: ...

Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: This looks like a missconfiguration. Can you post your properties file and an instantiation of a logger?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141601/how-to-set-log4j-with-unlimited-max-file-size) describes about setting max file size for log4j. Are you using RollingFileAppender? If that is the case then the default max file size for it is 10 MB, as stated in it's [api](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html). Increasing this limit should suffice the problem.